# Ajax Post Multiple Variables From Form

Tags: ajax, post, prototypejs

Firstly apologies if this is really simple but I have spent hours trying and quite a lot of Google searches for the information I believe I need to no avail.

Ok. So what I have is a form with 14 inputs that is dynamically filled using a get query. The user can then change the contents of the retrieved information and when complete press submit to update our database. The code I was using was working fine using separate pages and a lightbox setup to update the information however I wanted to integrate the update screen into the main page and use ajax to do the update post so to the user the rest of the page is still visible.

At present I have the following for my form:

```
<table border='1'>
<form id="Update" onsubmit="return false;">
<tr>
<th>Query</th>
<th>Result</th>
<tr/>
<tr>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<td>Estimating No:</td><td><input name="ID" id="ID" type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['q']; ?>" /></br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Date Received:</td><td><input type="text" name="Date_Received" id="Date_Received" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['Date_Received'] ) ); ?>" /><br/></td>
</tr>    
<tr>     
<td>X Ref:</td><td><input name="Xref" id="Xref" type="text" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['Xref'] ) ); ?>" /><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr>   
<td>Project Name:</td><td><input name="Project_Name" id="Project_Name" type="text" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['Project_Name'] ) ); ?>" /><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Location:</td><td><input name="Location" id="Location" type="text" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['Location'] ) ); ?>" /><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr>   
<td>Project Type:</td><td><input name="Project_Type" id="Project_Type" type="text" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['Project_Type'] ) ); ?>" /><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr>   
<td>Main Contractor:</td><td><input name="Main_Contractor" id="Main_Contractor" type="text" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['Main_Contractor'] ) ); ?>" /><br/>     </td>
</tr>
<tr>   
<td>Tender Sum:</td><td><input name="Tender_Sum" id="Tender_Sum" type="text" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['Tender_Sum'] ) ); ?>" /><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr>   
<td>Tender Return Date:</td><td><input name="Tender_Return_Date" id="Tender_Return_Date" type="text" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['Tender_Return_Date'] ) ); ?>" /><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr>   
<td>Jbsr Return Date:</td><td><input name="Jbsr_Return_Date" id="Jbsr_Return_Date" type="text" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['Jbsr_Return_Date'] ) ); ?>" /><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr>   
<td>Contact Name:</td><td><input name="Contact_Name" id="Contact_Name" type="text" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['Contact_Name'] ) ); ?>" /><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr>   
<td>Contact Number:</td><td><input name="Contact_Tel" id="Contact_Tel" type="text" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['Contact_Tel'] ) ); ?>" /><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr>   
<td>Contact Email:</td><td><input name="Contact_Email" id="Contact_Email" type="text" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['Contact_Email'] ) ); ?>" /><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr>   
<td>Project Status:</td><td><input name="Status" id="Status" type="text" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['Status'] ) ); ?>" /><br/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td><input type="submit" onClick="sendUpdate()" /></td>
</tr> 
</form>
```

Now my problem. After a lot of searching I have found a piece of code that seems to work however it will only work with one parameter. As you can see I need to post 14 in one go so it is no good as is. I have tried many combinations to try and get it working but to no avail. 
The code is:

```
<script>
    function sendUpdate() {
        new Ajax.Request("MenuUpdate1.php", 
            { 
            method: 'post', 
            postBody: 'ID='+$F('ID'),
            onComplete: showResponse 
            });
    }

    function showResponse(req){
        $('MenuUpdate').innerHTML= req.responseText;
    }
</script>
```

What I really need to know is how I can adapt the code above to allow me to post the additional 13 input boxes. Any help would be much appreciated and if you need me to clarify anything please ask.

Thanks in advance

Alan

Comment: @clockworkgeek im still majorly stuck on this. I have tried experienmenting with your code and still when I hit submit the php code of the page that is supposed to process the post information returns errors like the information was not posted. Can you assist me please?

Comment: I cannot guess what else might be wrong. May I see the live page with the javascript on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prototype excels at these sorts of operations. For reference see [`Ajax.Updater`](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Updater/) and [`Form.serialize`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Form/serialize/).

```
function sendUpdate() {
    new Ajax.Updater({success: 'MenuUpdate'}, 'MenuUpdate1.php', {
        parameters: Form.serialize('Update', true)
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @clockworkgeek,
Apologies for the delay in response I have been tied up at work and not had chance to properly apply your code above.

I have tried the code however My php in MenuUpdate1.php is return lots of errors based on undefined variables that would be the form items that I am trying to post to it.

Can I still use
    <code>   
    $ID = $_POST['ID'];
    $Date_Received = $_POST['Date_Received'];
    etc.
    </code>
to define a variable or do I need to change my coding

Comment: In your browser's console (usually the F12 key) try typing `Form.serialize('Update', true)` and see what is returned. It should be an object with attributes that match each input field. If not then that is the bit which needs fixing, otherwise the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Any public-facing software should sanitise ALL it's inputs regardless. Instead of `$ID = $_POST('ID')` do something like `$ID = (string) ( isset($_POST['ID']) ? $_POST['ID'] : '' )`

Comment: Ok so when I put Form.serialize('Update', true) in my browser console I get a whole host of information back but all of the different categories are all null. I thought maybe my problem is arising because the form I am trying to serialise has been taken from another document at a previous step however when I tried to serialise the form prior to my ajax get call the console returned an error that the form did not exist as opposed to simply everything was null. Therefore I assume I must have to tweak my form names or something else to make the serialise work.